# What is the most efficient way to merge items with the same type in a generic list in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, list, merge

**Example, I have the following interface and classes:**

```
public interface IRole {
    DateTime Since {get;}
    DateTime Until {get;}
}

public class Manager : IRole {
    public DateTime Since {get; private set;}
    public DateTime Until {get; private set;}
}
public class Employee : IRole {
    public DateTime Since {get; private set;}
    public DateTime Until {get; private set;}
}
public class Ceo: IRole {
    public DateTime Since {get; private set;}
    public DateTime Until {get; private set;}
}
```

**If a generic list contains the following items:**

```
list[0]=new Manager();
list[1]=new Manager();
list[2]=new Employee();
list[3]=new Manager();
list[4]=new Ceo();
list[5]=new Ceo();
```

**And I shall merge the same types, combine the Since/Until and shrink the items in list, so the output becomes:**

```
newList[0]=new Manager() //(Since is from list[0], Until is from list[1])
newList[1]=new Employee() //(list[2])
newList[2]=new Manager() //(list[3])
newList[3]=new Ceo() //(Since is from list[4], Until is from list[5])
```

*Please make sure you understand the question before answering as I have a history of being ambigous and I don't want to upset people. So please comment if you feel the "requirement" isn't clear.*

**My way is kind of dumb:**

```
for each item in list
    the current item shall always be merged into the previous item
        check if current item has the same type as the previous item
            get last item from newList and merge last item with current item
```

I was just wondering there must be a better solution.

**Updated:**

I just realize my "dumb solution" won't cover cases like more than 2 continuous items with the same type.

Example:

```
list[0]=new Manager();
list[1]=new Manager();
list[2]=new Employee();
list[3]=new Manager();
list[4]=new Ceo();
list[5]=new Ceo();
list[6]=new Ceo();
```

Comment: You suddenly switch to pseudocode in the third codeblock, am i right?

Comment: @Jourke van der Maas, is it better now? I just wanted to explain what the new object should be (the combination of all items that are next to each other with the same type).

Comment: rey Yeah, comments are clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post](http://tomasp.net/articles/custom-linq-grouping.aspx) about this :-).

It feels almost like `group by` except, you don't want to group elements globally. Instead, you only want to group elements that are adjacent in the input list. The blog post provides some code that allows you to change the meaning of `group by` in the LINQ query, so you could write just:

```
var groups =
  from person in list.WithAdjacentGrouping()
  group person by person.GetType().Name into g
  select new { 
    Type = g.Key,
    Since = new DateTime(g.Select(p => p.Since.Ticks).Min()),
    Until = new DateTime(g.Select(p => p.Until.Ticks).Max())
  }
```

The call to `WithAdjacentGrouping` specifes that grouping should only group adjacent elements. Then we can collect adjacent groups of persons by type (using `GetType().Name` as the key).

Finally, we return a collection that contains the name of the type (e.g. "Ceo") and two times - `Since` and `Until` that are calculated as minimal/maximal time from the collected group.

- See [Using custom grouping operators in LINQ](http://tomasp.net/articles/custom-linq-grouping.aspx) for the implementation of `WithAdjacentGrouping`

Comment: group by sounds good but how do you merge the properties like Since/Until?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Added calculation of minimal `Since` value / maximal `Until` value. Currently, it just returns them - do you want to create a new instance of e.g. `Ceo` or reuse an existing one (e.g. the first one in the group)?

Comment: this indeed is very clever why didn't I think of the solution in group by context... I do need to use reflection to create new instance as the Since/Until can only be passed in through constructor. But I get the idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeffrey: It is not _actually_ a `group by` (you need to use the alternative implementation from my blog to get it working as you need). However, the operation you want to do has the same structure as `group by`, which makes it possible to mis-use LINQ for encoding it nicely :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your pseudo code is dumb at all if it works as you expect it to. I don't believe you're going to find an easy shortcut for what you're trying to do, since it's a rather unusual algorithm. Bottom line: if this algorithm is not going to be run millions of times a day and the list doesn't have millions of objects in it, I wouldn't worry about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<IRole> newList = new Lis<IRole>();
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++) // Start at 1, so we can do i - 1 on the first iteration
{
  if (list[i - 1].GetType() != list[i].GetType()) // they're not the same
  {
    newList.Add(list[i - 1]); // so add the first one too
  }
  newList.Add(list[i]); // always add second one
}
```

Comment: I only did it so fast because I was curious what you wrote :)

Comment: @Jouke van der Maas, what happens if there are more than 2 items with the same type next to each other? like list[0]=manager, list[1]=manager and list[2]=manager?

Comment: @@Jouke van der Maas, I now think the looping should start from the last item, merge current with previous if same type and remove the last item from list (if possible at all), sounds like a while. Man... I just can't get the while loop out of my mind.

Comment: @jeffrey You're right, didn't think of that. As for looping backwards, you can do this: for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { }

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a very requirement specific thing. I am not sure if this is to be supported by a framework in anyway.
What happens if the type is not derived from IRole directly. What if there is something like IEmployee from which IManager is derived. I am not sure how application specific symentics can be understood by framework.

If the question is very specific to application, you may be able to use linq to get this done using group clause (on type). I haven't tried this before hence can't give you the exact solution.

Comment: Well the type is derivd from IRole by definition. He is not asking for a single method to do his work with IRole he is asking for an implementation.

Comment: Agreed. As i mentioned earlier, this is an application specific answer.